# NuGet restore progressive failures

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

Why would I be getting different NuGet restore build failures **on the exact same changeset** over 3 manually-triggered, consecutive builds?  The fourth build was successful.

I double checked on [NuGet's twitter feed](https://twitter.com/nuget) and there was no report of any issues or downtime.

This is occurring on the following command:

```
nuget.exe restore MySolution.sln
```

**FIRST BUILD:**

```
 Installing 'Microsoft.Data.Edm 5.6.2'.
 Installing 'Microsoft.Data.Services.Client 5.6.2'.
 Successfully installed 'Microsoft.Data.Edm 5.6.2'.
 Successfully installed 'Microsoft.Data.Services.Client 5.6.2'.
 Installing 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager 2.0.3'.
 Successfully installed 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager 2.0.3'.
 Installing 'Owin 1.0'.
 Successfully installed 'Owin 1.0'.
 Installing 'Microsoft.Data.OData 5.6.2'.
 Successfully installed 'Microsoft.Data.OData 5.6.2'.
 Installing 'System.Spatial 5.6.2'.
 Successfully installed 'System.Spatial 5.6.2'.
 Unable to find version '5.2.3' of package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client'.
 Unable to find version '5.2.3' of package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core'.
 Unable to find version '5.2.3' of package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin'.
 Unable to find version '3.0.1' of package 'Microsoft.Owin'.
 Unable to find version '3.0.1' of package 'Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb'.
 Unable to find version '6.0.8' of package 'Newtonsoft.Json'.
 Unable to find version '4.3.0' of package 'WindowsAzure.Storage'.
```

**SECOND BUILD:**

```
Installing 'Owin 1.0'.
Successfully installed 'Owin 1.0'.
Unable to find version '5.2.3' of package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client'.
Unable to find version '5.2.3' of package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core'.
Unable to find version '5.2.3' of package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin'.
Unable to find version '5.6.4' of package 'Microsoft.Data.Edm'.
Unable to find version '5.6.4' of package 'Microsoft.Data.OData'.
Unable to find version '5.6.4' of package 'Microsoft.Data.Services.Client'.
Unable to find version '3.0.1' of package 'Microsoft.Owin'.
Unable to find version '3.0.1' of package 'Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb'.
Unable to find version '3.1.0' of package 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager'.
Unable to find version '6.0.8' of package 'Newtonsoft.Json'.
Unable to find version '5.6.4' of package 'System.Spatial'.
Unable to find version '4.3.0' of package 'WindowsAzure.Storage'.
```

**THIRD BUILD:**

```
 Installing 'Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.8'.
 Installing 'Microsoft.Data.Edm 5.6.4'.
 Successfully installed 'Microsoft.Data.Edm 5.6.4'.
 Installing 'Microsoft.Data.Services.Client 5.6.4'.
 Successfully installed 'Microsoft.Data.Services.Client 5.6.4'.
 Installing 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin 5.2.3'.
 Installing 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 5.2.3'.
 Successfully installed 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin 5.2.3'.
 Successfully installed 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 5.2.3'.
 Installing 'Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb 3.0.1'.
 Successfully installed 'Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb 3.0.1'.
 Installing 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 5.2.3'.
 Successfully installed 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 5.2.3'.
 Installing 'Owin 1.0'.
 Successfully installed 'Owin 1.0'.
 Installing 'System.Spatial 5.6.4'.
 Installing 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager 3.1.0'.
 Installing 'WindowsAzure.Storage 4.3.0'.
 Successfully installed 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager 3.1.0'.
 Successfully installed 'System.Spatial 5.6.4'.
 Successfully installed 'WindowsAzure.Storage 4.3.0'.
 Successfully installed 'Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.8'.
 Unable to find version '5.6.4' of package 'Microsoft.Data.OData'.
 Unable to find version '3.0.1' of package 'Microsoft.Owin'.
```

**FOURTH BUILD:**

Success!

Comment: I have this problem with the Team City build server. Everything is restored fine until it gets to the Owin stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Host Build Controller on Visual Studio Online now performs NuGet implicitly.  It does not have the same problem!